# About SQL-injection in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-injection

I visited this [link](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html) about sql-injection. The way I use parameters is:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Something_Table] SET something = @something WHERE ID = 1;";

 var pParameter = new OleDbParameter("@something", OleDbType.Int);
                        pParameter.Value = something;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(pParameter);
```

But the link says `.Parameters.AddWithValue` method is simpler:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@something", something);
```

What's the main different between these? Can I choose to do `AddWithValue` instead without any consequences?

Comment: You might want to read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: You can also precheck `something` by yourself to be sure, no injective code is in your string. This refers to `Parameters.AddWithValue`

Comment: Why would you do that @lokusking having sql parameters?